# delay/cancel linux shutdown

Tags: linux, bash, shutdown, aws, amazon-ec2

I know that similar questions were answered multiple times here, and my question may look weird, but my case is different. I would like to catch the linux shutdown command **before** another processes, show a message on the UI, and postpond/cancel the shutdown.

**This is the situation:**
We use virtual machines for work (Amazon workspaces). We have root access on this machines, but `another people` as well (e.g. security guys). The `another people` do not respect us and they restart often the Linux workspaces while we work on the machines. We work in applications with UI (i.e. Intellij IDE), sometimes in terminal.
Unfotunately there is no alert that warn us about restart is comming or here. I do not know how the `another people` restarts the virtual workspaces, with delay or without delay.

What I would like to have:

1. Run a script at the background that catches the shutdown signal
2. Catch the shutdown signal **before** it arrives to any applications!
3. Show up a UI warning (not a terminal message).
4. Then block the shutdown, and allow us to restart manually the machine later.

I know that I can catch the signal with `trap` in a bash script and cancel the signal with `shutdown -c` but sometimes it is too late and the signal kills another running user processes before my script can do anything.

The question is can I catch and cancel somehow the shutdown signal before any other processes catch them, and cancel the shutdown on time?

Maybe there are existing tool, ready for use that handles this situation but not sure.

Believe or not, we tried to talk with `another people` multiple times. Another issue is when the shutdown hapens out of working hours, then shutdown must postpond too because we just close the remote desktop and do not save the work because next morning we will come back.

How to define the working hours is another question if you work from different time zones.

The main question is how to catch the shutdown signal **before** it arrives to any applications and cancel it.

Comment: Do not try to solve social problems with technology. You have a problem with a person, solve with such person. And it will be a lesson to you and to him.

Comment: Not only is this a social issue, it is also a conceptual/planning issue. "Security guys" are usually managing a server, which shouldn't have developers logged in graphical sessions in the first place, and vice versa: development machines shouldn't be servers at the same time.

Comment: You will be surprised if you see this environment. This is not a one-man show, this is not an issue between two teams. This is wide issue between ...., across countries. Developers use virtual machines (AWS) for work.

Comment: @Vilinkameni You can come here and tell "another guys" this is the rule of thumb. There are multiple teams with admin rights (sec team, Unix admins, update team, etc.) and all of them restart the workspaces as they wish. So that would be great if we can solve this problem on a programmatic way. The management way failed.

Comment: It doesn't logically make much sense. If both of you have root access, he can annihilate whatever you have set up as well. The "only way" that might sort of work is that the whole system (init / kernel / ...) is built in the way that it simply doesn't support shutdown at all (like on both init level and ACPI support level, etc.).

Comment: `annihilate whatever you have set up`: yes, but nobody do this  :) They just always add some new "clever" staff at the top of the AWS. Actually we can block them to connect or we can remove what they did/installed because we are admins as well, but this is not a solution. They are guys with strong support (e.g. what sec team tells is stronger then the Universe)  so this hacking is not a solution. Only delay somehow the initialized restart is the solution. This issue does not exist on Windows because there are nice management tools that allow us to delay the restart. This is a Unix issue only.

Comment: The only solution here is to complain to `another people`'s manager.

Comment: Either your security(?) folks shouldn't be restarting a server without warning, or you shouldn't be using it. There is no middle ground here for a professionally run environment: it is simply not acceptable to restart a production grade server without warning and consideration

Answer (score 7):

> [C]an I catch and cancel somehow the shutdown signal before any other processes catch them, and cancel the shutdown on time?

This isn't possible. If they want to shut it down, they can just tell the kernel to shut down the machine immediately and bypass all userspace mechanisms (using the `reboot` syscall, for example), and there's no way to prevent that.

In a virtual environment like yours it's even more dire, since they can simply tear down the container or shut down the VM in a way that you will get no notification at all.

> I know that I can catch the signal with trap in a bash script

You are mistaken about what happens when you trap these signals. When shutting down gracefully, your init system sends `SIGTERM` and eventually `SIGKILL` to running processes. These are just indications to your system that the system will shut down imminently and the application should save its work. Importantly, these are not a negotiation, but a directive to save work: even if you trap `SIGTERM`, it will not stop or delay the shutdown.

Some ideas which may mitigate the disruption:

1. Automate the saving of your work at regular intervals in your IDE. While this will not solve the problem of your unexpected shutdowns, it could minimise data loss.
2. Consider working on a local machine and synchronising your work with the virtual machine via `rsync` or using your VCS. This way, even if the VM is shut down, you still have access to your work.

While some of these technical solutions may partially mitigate the issue, they don't address the core problem, which seems to be a lack of communication or respect between different parties with access to the machine. If you prevent them from shutting down the machine one way, they will no doubt do it another way. I suggest you look more at social solutions.

Comment: Thanks for this post, this is not about solutions, but really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the comment points out the right solution is to talk to the individuals that are causing the problem. If that fails escalate the issue through management.

However just for fun I did think about how you could solve the problem and I think you are designing a solution that is way more complex than it needs to be, specifically you could just add the following to roots .bashrc:

```
alias reboot="killall -9 -u securityguy1 -u securityguy2 -u securityguy3"
```

Since typically the only message you get when you do a reboot remotely is that you're kicked off the machine and the command above will kick off all the listed users...

Again don't do this - I won't be held liable for you getting fired.

Comment: This might sort of work if the security guys have bad security practices. Most likely they login with a personal account and `sudo reboot` which will bypass shell aliases.

Comment: You could of course move the `reboot` binary out the way and put in shell script with the same line and you may also want to grab roots tty and explicitly kill the corresponding shell in case the person had logged in directly as root with an SSH key - however that was a long post for something that you shouldn't do...   .... Yes I did give it quite a bit of thought...